# constant equivaleny for dynamic variables

Tags: php

I can access static class variables without using dangerous eval like

```
$aa = icon;
echo StaticClass::chat{$aa}; 

equivalent is :
constant("StaticClass::chat$aa")
```

however i have no idea how to do the same if staticClass is not static.

i.e need to accesss

```
$StaticClass->get$aafunc(); // geticonfunc()
```

Pleas help ?

Comment: Use google http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: What does "staticClass is not static" mean?

Comment: I don't see where there's anything to do with *constants* in the updated question.

Comment: i know d function constant so looking equivalent for dynamic

Comment: You're asking how to call a *method* on an object where the method name is in a variable?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this :

```
<?php

class test {
    public static $xyz = "static xyz content";

    public static function foo() {
        return "result of static foo function";
    }

    public $wxyz = "wxyz content";

    public function bar() {
        return "result of bar method";
    }
}

$xyzName  = "xyz";
$fooName  = "foo";
$wxyzName = "wxyz";
$barName  = "bar";

$instance = new test();

echo (test::$$xyzName)."<br />";
echo (test::$fooName())."<br />";
echo ($instance->$wxyzName)."<br />";
echo ($instance->$barName())."<br />";

?>
```

It returns :

```
static xyz content<br />
result of static foo function<br />
wxyz content<br />
result of bar method<br />
```

Comment: That's accessing a static property via variable property names, not constants (or methods for that matter as shown in the update).

Comment: I completed my answer